# get event when a new (external) program is running with API on C#?

Tags: c#, events, api

i'm writing a C# program, and i want to know if there is any way to get notify when a new program is running, without checking every time the task manager and the processes, just like a C# event... 
or like some hook.. (like SetWindowsHookEx)?
thank you!
Shiran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [ManagementEventWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementeventwatcher.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Following article shows you how to use WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation) to do that in C#:

[`Using WMI to monitor process creation, deletion and modification in .NET`](http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/archive/2006/02/11/438006.aspx)

Comment: +1 I agree this is a much easier solution than a Windows hook. Especially since I just got finished writing way too much code to implement a global mouse hook in a .NET app.